# Error image resize changing class from javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I have an horizontal slider with one column (image 2)

```
<div id="portfolio_horizontal_container" class="onecolumn">
```

If i do:

```
<div id="portfolio_horizontal_container" class="two-ver-columns">
```

and refresh the browser, the slider has two columns now (image 3)

But if i make the change with `js`:

```
  $("#verPrincipal").click(function() {
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("onecolumn");
    })

    $("#verCuadricula").click(function() {
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("two-ver-columns");
    })
```

> images are incorrectly adjusted (image 1)

I don't understand why in one way it allows me to change, but in the other it doesn't

> captures

[image: La vista inicial del sitio]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Demo:

```js
$("#verPrincipal").click(function() {
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("onecolumn");
})

$("#verCuadricula").click(function() {
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("two-ver-columns");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="verPrincipal">One Column</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button id="verCuadricula">Two Column</button>
</div>

<div id="portfolio_horizontal_container" class="onecolumn">
aaaa
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any other classes that might be attached to that element? Can you share your CSS?

Comment: This should work fine. Can you create a small demo for this on codepen or others.

Comment: @palaѕн i'm sorry, i'm using ``bloom`` template http://bloom.kwst.net/site/light/index.html ,
I can't create a demo because the slider uses many plugins, and I don't know how to make it work in codepen

Comment: I have added a snippet for you in the end. try to update `portfolio_horizontal_container` with just two images to show the issue, if possible. It just css issue. so, two images and class names and some css should reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just verified that if I change the size of the browser, the problem is solved. As I told you, I am not able to reproduce the example. Is there a way to make some kind of imperceptible resize? I think that would solve the problem

Comment: I think, the library you are using is adjusting the images, it takes the styles and handles it, while on other hand when you are dynamically changing layout library is not handling it, as you didn't code for it

Comment: @AgustinG.As I said on resize library is handling it.

Comment: Just look into the library and find a method which will refresh the layout

Answer (score 0):

> Solved with:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

>

```
$("#verPrincipal").click(function() {
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("onecolumn");
  $(window).trigger('resize');
})

$("#verCuadricula").click(function() {
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
  $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("two-ver-columns");
  $(window).trigger('resize');
})
```